# Call a class from list

Tags: python, pygame

I have 3 classes that look pretty much like this. just different names:

```
class CrossPipe(BasePipe):
    def __init__(self, position):
        BasePipe.__init__(self, position)
        self.current_pos_X = 0
        self.current_pos_y = 0
        self.flow_rect = Rect(0,0,settings.FLOW_WIDTH, 0)
        self.flow_rect.left = (settings.TUBE_SIZE / 2) - (settings.FLOW_WIDTH / 2)
        
    def update(self):
        BasePipe.update(self)
        if self.current_pos_y < settings.TUBE_SIZE:
            self.current_pos_y += 1
        self.flow_rect.bottom = self.current_pos_y
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, settings.FLOW_COLOR, self.flow_rect, 1)
```

Each of the classes is a block for a game. The blocks go randomly in a list 4 at a time.

```
pipes = (StraightPipe, BentPipe, CrossPipe)
coming_pipes = []
done = 0
while done != 4:
    coming_pipes.append(random.choice(pipes).__name__)
    done += 1
```

This Makes a list that looks like this:

```
['BentPipe', 'CrossPipe', 'BentPipe', 'StraightPipe']
```

The 4 blocks in the list need show up on the screen, but in order to draw them on the screen i have to be able to call them from the list with `placed.add(coming_pipes[0]((-2,0)))` but since its a list of strings it gives `placed.add("BentPipe"((-2,0)))` which cant be called.

So, how can i call a class from a list, or add the classes to the list without it being a string?

I dont have much coding knowledge btw.

Comment: Just don't bother with the `__name__` but add the classes themselves. (Although it might be easier in practice to have the *instances* in the array, rather than the classes - if you know in advance which arguments you're going to give to the constructor.)

Comment: Just remove the `.__name__`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Then the list will look like this:
 [<class 'straight_pipe.StraightPipe'>, <class 'cross_pipe.CrossPipe'>, <class 'straight_pipe.StraightPipe'>, <class 'bent_pipe.BentPipe'>]

Comment: @AndreasSB02 So? You don't care about what the list looks like; you care about being able to call the elements of the list in order to create an instance.

Comment: @AndreasSB02 and what's the problem with that? It means your list contains the classes that you can call as you want. Don't worry about the fact that their string representations look "strange".

Comment: @RobinZigmond nono, cause if i call the class from the list it will look like this: placed.add(<class 'straight_pipe.StraightPipe'>((-2,3))) and i get a syntax error

Comment: huh? If you just do what you say you want to: `placed.add(coming_pipes[0]((-2,0)))` that should work fine.

Comment: wow, i swear i tried that before... Thanks anyways, it worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the *names* of the classes in the list; put the classes themselves.

```
pipes = (StraightPipe, BentPipe, CrossPipe)
coming_pipes = []
done = 0
while done != 4:
    coming_pipes.append(random.choice(pipes))
    done += 1
```

or more simply

```
coming_pipes = random.choices(pipes, k=4)
```

Comment: Or just `coming_pipes = random.choices(pipes, k=4)`.

Comment: I think for OP's learning the list comprehension was worth leaving in there in addition to choices.